# Jenkins build with parameters display issues

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Using **Jenkins 2.303.2**, if I am using build with parameters, then its showing *"parameter_name"* and defined *"parameter_values"* in different lines. It was displaying both in one line in some previous Jenkins build. Is there any way to fix this?

**Example:**

[image]

Question:
*How can I display parameter_value just besides parameter_name" Example-*
[image]